# Is SQL Azure Reporting reliable?

Tags: azure

I'd like to migrate applications on windows azure and I use Ms Reporting services.

I know there is a azure reporting ctp but is it reliable ?

My reports aren't very complicated but I cannot deploy applications if not reliable.

And do you know a release day for sql azure reporting ? And what will be the level of compatility with azure ?

Regards

Comment: [SQL Reporting will discontinue service on October 31, 2014.](http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/pricing/details/sql-reporting/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It does seem to be reliable, but the performance can be quite poor on large reports.

No RTM dates have been released.

I suggest you give your reports a try, and see what you think.

Comment: I asked for a test. what was the delay to obtain an invitation code ?